# 1.9 Executing as AreaEffectClouds

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get a public server ready for the 1.9 release on monday, and I'm running the 1.9 Pre-Release 3 right now. From what I understand, the Area Effect Clouds are entities and can be used in the same way that armor stands were used in 1.8.

I'm trying to do an execute as command to catch when a player is within a radius of the Area Effect Cloud and then give them boots. Is this something that's not supported with these entities? The is the command I'm trying to use (the /give command was tested on it's own, so the issue isn't there)

```
/execute @a[type=AreaEffectCloud,name=Boots] ~ ~ ~ /give @a[r=2,c=1] minecraft:leather_boots 1 0 {ench:[{id:8,lvl:3}],display:{Name:"PropertyOfSpawn",color:16759060}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm a twit. I changed the @a to @e and that solved the problem.

```
/execute @e[type=AreaEffectCloud,name=Boots] ~ ~ ~ /give @a[r=2,c=1] minecraft:leather_boots 1 0 {ench:[{id:8,lvl:3}],display:{Name:"PropertyOfSpawn",color:16759060}}
```

Comment: Could you post he working command? It may help someone else, if they find this question later.

Comment: Lol. We've all made silly mistakes like that before! :P